# Word to describe the sound of an utterance that has an undertone of being disgruntled

Tags: expressions

I am looking for a verb to explain a tone that implies that the speaker is disgruntled, similar to what an employer would sound like while firing an employee for a stupid mistake that has caused a lot of harm to the company. For example, the word growl or hiss has the undertone of anger or frustration.

A phrase to explain the same (e.g., "an edge in the voice") will also help.

Answer (score 2):

The term [gruff](https://www.google.com/webhp?&ion=1#q=define%3A%20gruff) comes to mind:

- abrupt or taciturn in manner.

  - "penetrate a gruff exterior and you will find him affable"
  - synonyms: abrupt, brusque, curt, short, blunt, bluff, no-nonsense;
- (of a voice) rough and low in pitch.

  - "she spoke with a gruff, masculine voice"
  - synonyms:   rough, guttural, throaty, gravelly, husky, croaking, rasping, raspy, growly, hoarse, harsh;

Answer (score 0):

Consider **a harsh tone of voice**.

Example: *Depending on their temperament, young children may be easily frightened or made anxious by a harsh tone of voice used by a parent whom they normally trust and rely upon*.